# Distribute n identical objects into r distinct groups

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a separate formula for calculating distribution of n identical objects into r distinct groups? I read this particular concept in a book but did not understand it. Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Also, what exactly do u mean by distinct groups? Does that mean that the groups differ on the basis of no of objects they contain? Or, if u think of groups as boxes, does it mean the boxes itself are different regardless of no of objects in them?

EDIT : How would the answer differ if instead of distinct groups/boxes, we have identical groups/boxes?

Comment: Its something like marbles and people. So suppose you want to give 100 marbles to four people. The dollars are all the same, but the persons are not. So giving 3 marbles to John and 5 to Ben is not the same as giving 5 to John and 3 to Ben. However all marbles are the same, so all that matters is how many marbles each person gets.

Comment: So sir, this problem should have the same answer as if the groups/boxes are identical, right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

Comment: @user34304 no, you are counting some combinations more than once, giving for dollars to Joe and 3 to Tony and giving 3 to Joe and 4 to Tony where different when the boxes (Joe and Tony) where different. However now the boxes are the same, so Joe and Tony become indistinguishable persons, that is giving 4 to joe and 3 to Tony would be the same as 3 to Joe and 4 to Tony, so you are counting some cases more than once.

Answer (score 19):

This is called stars and bars method. suppose the stars are objects and space between bars represents objects corresponding to a certain group. Here is a visual representation:

$\underbrace{*****}_{\text{first group}}|\underbrace{******}_{\text{second group}}|\underbrace{*****}_\text{third group}|\underbrace{**}_\text{fourth group}$

Check each arrangement of bars provides a unique group separation and each group separation corresponds to a unique bar arrangement.Also check to seperate the stars in n groups only (n-1) bars are required.

then all you need to do is see how many bar arrangements are possible. Observe that when you have the $n-1$ bars and $k$ stars (assuming there are k objects to sort into n groups) then there are $n-1+k$ positions the stars and bars can take. So there are $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$ ways to chose the positions of the bars.

---

The problem gets harder when the boxes are identical, because for example: he following arrangements are the same: $*|***|**$ and $**|*|***$ In the problem where the boxes are different the answer would somehow correspond to distributing coins between people. When the boxes are identical however it corresponds to finding the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of the number into x or less non-zero parts. So if we define $p_k(n)$ to be the number of partitions of n numbers into exactly $k$ non-zero pieces then we get the number of ways to put n identical marbles into k identical boxes is $\sum_{k=0}^np_k$. However there is no pretty formula to calculate $p_k$ or $\sum_{k=0}^np_k$.

Comment: What about the case where the groups are identical?

Comment: Does this help you?

Comment: @JorgeFernández I can't understand one thing that how does the stars and bars method ensure that $n-1$ bars will be placed into the distinct places i.e. the bars don't overlap each other.

Comment: It foesn't, if two overlap it means that there are no stars between those bars. If you want to ensure at least 1 for each category just take away 1 star for each category and do the same. so the formula would be $\binom{k-1}{n-1}$

Comment: @JorgeFernández Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @JorgeFernández sorry to disturb you again on a doubt from this question but I have no clue about it.My doubt is will the stars and bars method still be valid if we replaced the stars with distinct objects?

Comment: Yes it can, the answer will be the same if the stars are any object you want it to

Comment: @JorgeFernández Won't we have to multiply $C(n+k-1, n-1)$ by $k!$ if the $k$ objects are distinct and the order of objects in the boxes matters?