# Distributing balls in boxes.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can $n$ identical balls be distributed amongst $m$ different boxes given that a box can have any number of balls(from $0$ to $n$)?

What I've tried is using multinomial theorem to find the answer but that becomes a tedious task, here's what I made up:

> For a given box, the can possibly be $0,1,2,3...(n-1),n$ balls.
>
> Writing it in the form:
> $(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 ... + x^{\text n-1} + x^n)$
> Since there a $m$ boxes which such possibilities so they can multiplied and written as:
> $(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 ... + x^{\text n-1} + x^n)^m$
> And since in total there are $n$ balls, therefore we can find the coefficient of $x^n$ in the given product.

But that becomes a lengthy process for bigger values of $m$ and $n$, and I'm unable to generalize it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: How many ways can *n* balls be put into 1 box? 2 boxes? 3 boxes. Working through this should put you in good stead.

Comment: This link will be helpful as it contains answer:


   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618491/distribute-n-identical-objects-into-r-distinct-groups

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract thanks that helped.

Comment: @Nikhil H Take care, that the solution is in fact $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$ **not** $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$ possible ways as your problem differs slightly, in that the balls are *identical*, and therfore can be considered indistinguishable. [Enumeration](http://msor.victoria.ac.nz/foswiki/pub/Courses/MATH261_2014T1/PrintedNotes/261-2014-notesIV.pdf)

Comment: @Nic aren't the balls identical in both cases.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract I agree it is confusing. Consider $\binom{4+2-1}{4}$ That is number of ways to put 4 balls into 2 boxes, which should be $5: (0,4), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (4,0)$.