# How many ways to choose group of numbers with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

I'm taking a combinatorics course, and I was trying to practice from a book I took from the library. unfortunately there are no answers in this book, and there was a question I didn't know even how to approach to. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could give me an advice on how to think about it:

> Given the group $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$,  choose $r$ different numbers so that no two are sequential. e.g for $r = 3$ and $n>r$,  $\{1,3,5\}$ is a valid group but $\{1,4,5\}$ isn't valid.

Thank you very much for your time and attention!

Comment: Please refer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030145/combinatorics-question-about-choosing-non-consecutive-integers and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490405/choosing-numbers-without-consecutive-numbers

Comment: what is it asking for? express the number of valid groups in terms of n and r?

Comment: thank you very much. I'm sorry, I've tried looking for similar problems, but haven't encountered those posts.